# Positive measure of a Lebesgue measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Here E is a Lebesgue measurable set in $R$. Show if the following is true or false:

1. Every uncountable measurable sets must have positive measure.
2. Every set with positive outer measure is Lebesgue measurable.

Can someone please answer this. I am not sure if uncountable sets are measurable or not. Also, can the outer measure be negative in the case of part 1?. I know if m*(E)=0 then E is measurable so does that mean part 2 is false? I am mixing up these two cases so can someone please answer them?

Comment: 1. Cantor set. 2. Take any non-measurable subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ and look at $A \cup (1,2)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If $A$ is a non-measurable set you don't need $A\cup(1,2)$, $A$ itself has positive outer measure. But I suppose your example is better because it even has positive inner measure.

Comment: @bof Right. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @MemphisMermelade a common example of a set that is not Lebesgue measurable is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) (Vitaii set)